# Add column to CSV file with powershell AzureVM

Tags: powershell, azure, calculated-columns

Not sure how to explain this, we're doing an assessment on disk usage on Azure, to reduce costs. We are trying to asses the space on each vm and reduce the disks

I'd like to add a recommendation column in there based on the free space, if the freespace is greater than 90% then add a comment "consider resizing" if less than 15% then "consider disk clean up".

The script I have works fine except it doesn't add the comment in, first I tried this...

```
$computers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like 'VM-*'").Name | Sort-Object
foreach ($computer in $Computers) 
{
$vol = gwmi Win32_volume -Computer $Computer -Filter 'DriveType = 3'
#$vol

$info = $vol | select PsComputerName, DriveLetter, Label,
           @{n='Capacity';e={[int]($_.capacity/1GB)}}, 
           @{n='FreeSpace';e={[int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
           @{n='FreeSpace (%)';e={[int](($_.FreeSpace) / ($_.capacity) * 100.0)}}
           if ('FreeSpace (%)' -gt 85)
           {
           Write-Output "Disk Usage Low, Consider Resizing Options"
           }
           else 
           {
           Write-Output "Disk Usage High"
           }
$info  | Export-Csv "c:\temp\tempfiles\question.csv" -Append
}
```

That didn't work, I then tried adding another section, where I get true or false, which seems to work.. that one is below, however I need to dd recommendations in..

```
$computers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like 'VM-*'").Name | Sort-Object
foreach ($computer in $Computers) 
{
$vol = gwmi Win32_volume -Computer $Computer -Filter 'DriveType = 3'
#$vol

$info = $vol | select PsComputerName, DriveLetter, Label,
           @{n='Capacity';e={[int]($_.capacity/1GB)}}, 
           @{n='FreeSpace';e={[int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
           @{n='FreeSpace (%)';e={[int](($_.FreeSpace) / ($_.capacity) * 100.0)}},
           @{n='Recommendation';e={[String] ($_.FreeSpace -gt 90)}}

$info  | Export-Csv "c:\temp\tempfiles\question.csv" -Append
}
```

Hope that makes sense.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `e` stands for `Expression`. So you should be able to use an expression in there, using the original object properties (i.e. not your custom property names such as `FreeSpace (%)`)

```
$computers = (Get-AdComputer -Filter "name -like 'VM-*'").Name | Sort-Object
foreach ($computer in $Computers) 
{
$vol = gwmi Win32_volume -Computer $Computer -Filter 'DriveType = 3'
#$vol

$info = $vol | select PsComputerName, DriveLetter, Label,
           @{n='Capacity';e={[int]($_.capacity/1GB)}}, 
           @{n='FreeSpace';e={[int]($_.FreeSpace/1GB)}},
           @{n='FreeSpace (%)';e={[int](($_.FreeSpace) / ($_.capacity) * 100.0)}},
           @{n='Recommendation';e={
                if((($_.FreeSpace) / ($_.capacity) * 100.0) -gt 90){
                    "Disk Usage Low, Consider Resizing Options"
                }elseif((($_.FreeSpace) / ($_.capacity) * 100.0) -gt 75){
                    "Something else"
                }else{
                    "Disk Usage High"
                }
            }

$info  | Export-Csv "c:\temp\tempfiles\question.csv" -Append
}
```

Comment: Thanks everyone, I see what I was doing, I was looking for the value generated in the previous column rather than creating the value from the formula.. Doh! is there a way to put a range in there, so for example if its between 75-90 write "blah" and above 90 write "blah blah"  .. thanks again for your help :)

Comment: @NorrinRad See edit ;-). This works because the first if already takes care of `90+`, so the second if only needs to check for `75+` - it does not need the upper limit. You can add as many `elseif`s as required.

Comment: excellent thanks, managed to get everything into one column .. thanks so much for your help :)